# PHP MySQL Uploading Large Data by rows VS at once

Tags: php, mysql

I've read many posts in SO and some of them are advising to compile all INSERT statements then do `mysqli_multi_query` but some of them says you should execute each INSERT query one at a time for better performance. What is the best way to upload 9000+ rows of records to MySQL database?

The file is from CSV file so I use `fgetcsv to read each then I create an INSERT statement for each records/rows so I can execute them all at once with`mysqli_multi_query`. Now I am trying to modify that code to turn it into a prepared-statement type to be safe but I want to know the best way to do this first so I won't have to modify the code ever again.

Is it advisable to call each INSERT query?

Comment: You can import the whole file using [DATA LOAD INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) statement.

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` - it should be 5 to 10 times faster at least

Comment: I tried using LOAD DATA INFILE in the past and I forgot why but it wasn't working for me. Also, isn't LOAD DATA INFILE not safe?